# Services throwing unknown provider error - Angularjs Unit Testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to fix some broken unit tests that were set up a long time ago. For some reason when we run the tests they all fail citing an "unknown provider error" that we get for every service inject. I've done a lot of searching and I can't see any apparent issue with the test. If nothing is wrong with the test, could this be a config issue? I've played around with the order the files are loaded and it doesn't seem to matter.

```
"use strict";

describe("Catalogs controller", function() {

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module("photonControllersPreSession"));



  var $rootScope;

  var $scope;
  var createController;
  var $window;
  var $location;
  var loggerService;
  var catalogService;
  var feedbackService;


  beforeEach(
    inject( function(
      $controller,
      _$rootScope_,
      _$window_,
      _$location_,
      _loggerService_,
      _catalogService_,
      _feedbackService_
    ) {
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      $window = _$window_;
      $location = _$location_;
      loggerService = _loggerService_;
      catalogService = _catalogService_;
      feedbackService = _feedbackService_;
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();

      spyOn(loggerService, "info");

      createController = function() {
        return $controller("CatalogController", {
          $scope: $scope,
          $location: $location,
          $window: $window,
          loggerService: _loggerService_,
          catalogService: _catalogService_,
          feedbackService: _feedbackService_
        });
      };
    })
  );


  it("Should init", function() {
    var catalogController = null;
    catalogController = createController();
    console.log("test: " + createController);


    // Just want to see if the controller is created.
    expect(catalogController).not.toBe(null);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS do require all modules to be loaded before starting tests. You have only one module `photonControllersPreSession` included to this particular tests suite.

Make sure, that `CatalogController`, `loggerService`, `catalogService`, `feedbackService` are belong to `photonControllersPreSession` module, or their modules are included to the `photonControllersPreSession` as well.

E.g., if `loggerService` is a part of some other module, lets say `mySuperModule`, make sure `mySuperModule` has been included like so

```
angular.module('photonControllersPreSession', [
  'mySuperModule'  
]);
```

otherwise you have to include all the modules manually before each test

```
beforeEach(() => {
  module('mySuperModule');
  module('photonControllersPreSession');
});
```

Comment: This was definitely the case. Thanks!